# Null Variables in PHP Functions

Tags: php, function, variables, null

I have a question for default null variables in php functions inside class.

```
public function myFunction($var1, $var2, $var3 = NULL, $var4 = NULL){
//My Class Function
}
```

Think that i'll use myFunction in a script.

if i want to user $var1, $var2, $var3 i'll call function like that

```
$C = New myClass();
$C->myFunction($var1,$var2,$var3);
```

if i don't use $var4, NULL is assaigned to $var4.

if i want to use function like this

```
$C = New myClass();
$C->myFunction($var1,$var2,$var4);
```

$var4 and $var3 will mix. How can i use it correctly ?

Comment: I think part of the problem is that you use the same variable names for both the formal and the actual parameters. This may confuse things. In reality, they are different variables! So if you use different names in the calling routine, say `$this, $that, $theother`, it will become clear that the order of things is not dictated by the variable names, and thus, what the solution is.

Answer (score 2):

Skip the relevant item by sending `NULL`

```
$C = New myClass();
$C->myFunction($var1,$var2,NULL,$var4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write `$C->myFunction($var1, $var2, null, $var4);` to skip `$var3` and use `$var4`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think that the only way is because if you want to not send a parameter or you set it to null, or only the last parameter cannot be send and assign to it value null:

```
$C = New myClass();
$C->myFunction($var1,$var2,NULL,$var4);
```

Documentation of function argument here:
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php